# byte vs char length semantics in sqlplus

Tags: oracle

The following code works fine in SQLDeveloper

```
declare
x varchar2(5 char);
begin
select 'üüüü' into x from dual;
end;
/
```

But when I run it in sqlplus I get

```
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

I get a similar error when I in sqldeveloper changes the variable declaration to

```
x varchar2(5 BYTE)
```

The question is: why do I get the error in sqlplus and not in sqldeveloper?

Comment: SQL*Plus for some reason is reporting it takes 6 bytes to store that character and SQL Developer is reporting only 2. It is a multi-byte character in the Unicode spec...SQL*Plus isn't unicode compliant out of the box so not sure where it's going squirrely. But run this and you'll see why SQL*Plus isn't happy
SQL> select lengthb('ü') from dual;
LENGTHB('??')
-------------
     6

Comment: so your character is considered a unicode supplementary character and docs show that ' The supplementary characters are treated as two separate, user-defined characters that occupy 6 bytes' https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm and sqldev has full unicode support and is able to avoid this, somehow, my guess

Comment: What is the value of NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `NLS_LANG` properly. Here is an example.

I use [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) for SSH client, with UTF-8 settings.

```
[oracle@o73 ~]$ file test.sql
test.sql: UTF-8 Unicode text

[oracle@o73 ~]$ cat test.sql
declare
  x varchar2(5 char);
begin
  select 'üüüü' into x from dual;
end;
/
[oracle@o73 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 7 19:04:00 2018
Version 18.2.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.2.0.0.0

SQL> @test
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4


SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.2.0.0.0
[oracle@o73 ~]$ export NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
[oracle@o73 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 7 19:04:13 2018
Version 18.2.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.2.0.0.0

SQL> @test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

SQL Developer handles this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters;
```

and compare the output.